# What is the relationship between Agni and Yama?

Tags: vedas, agni, yama

Agni - God of Fire

Yama - God of Death.

What is the relationship between them?

Comment: If possible, please elaborate on the question. Why do you think there might be some relation between the both? Did you read some articles regarding that? Try to share more information in question so that users can find it easy to answer the question.

Comment: @hanugm Agni is perhaps the former Yama.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agni#Significance